# Cosa intende Pavese con «arrivare» in questa lettera?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

In una famosa [lettera](https://ecosidimenticammolerose.blogspot.com/2010/07/e-questo-e-tutto.html) di Pavese a Fernanda Pivano egli scrive:

> *Si ritorna cioè a quanto Le ho sempre consigliato: si faccia una vita interiore - di studio, di affetti, d'interessi umani che non siano
>   soltanto di «**arrivare**», ma di «**essere**»*

(enfasi mia)

Ma che cosa si intende per "arrivare" ed "essere" in questo contesto, ossia gli interessi umani?

Comment: Forse “arrivare” nel senso carrieristico e ambizioso,  mentre “essere” nel senso di persona con dei valori.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il senso, già suggerito da @Gio nei commenti, si chiarisce considerando la conclusione del consiglio di Cesare Pavese: « - e vedrà che la vita avrà un significato». Lo studio, gli affetti e gli interessi non dovrebbero essere, secondo Pavese, solo strumentali a raggiungere obiettivi ambizioni, o successi, ma aiutarla a “essere” (il meglio che può, umanamente).

Comment: Sì, in questa chiave torna tutto - ed è un augurio molto bello da fare ad una persona.